# JavaScript files inclusion in specific order

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have some `JavaScript` files that I want to include in my application in such order that these following 3 files:

```html
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.js"></script>
<script src="lib/custom.js"></script>
```

Always execute after these 6:

```html
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="lib/custom1.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/DBData/InMemoryProvider.js"></script>
<script src="lib/DBData/SpookyHealthEntities.js"></script>
```

Currently, I am doing like this:

```html
<script src="lib/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="lib/custom1.js"></script>
<script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/DBData/InMemoryProvider.js"></script>
<script src="lib/DBData/SpookyHealthEntities.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/jquery-mobile-angular-adapter.js"></script>
<script src="lib/custom.js"></script>
```

But in this way, the last 3 execute before the first completes, so I am getting an error because, in the last 3 files, some code has to execute once the first 6 complete their whole execution.

Comment: I recommend looking into [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: "But in this way last 3 executes before the first completes", scripts are executed synchronously in order, so this is not possible. You probably have a different problem

Comment: `<script src="lib/DBData/SpookyHealthEntities.js"></script>`
in this file i am load data using JayData to webSql so before it completes my custom js files executes in my custom file i get data from webSql

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to use include mechanism to include all the dependent files from the parent file. This way you can be certain of the loading as you want it to.

for example if a is dependent upon b and b on c, you will do the following.

Add include statement at the top of a for b and in b, an included statement for c.

Hope it helps.